# associate security group to vpc awscli

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-security-group

I need to associate security group to VPC trough awscli,
I have 4 security groups that I created and I want to use them multiply times for all the clusters I am going to create, IS there a way to associate an existing security group to a newly created VPC? Is that he right way to do it?

I saw that there is a way like that following command that  creates a security group for the specified VPC:

```
$ aws ec2 create-security-group --group-name my-sg --description "My security group" --vpc-id vpc-1a2b3c4d
{
    "GroupId": "sg-903004f8"
}
```

But I only wants to associate  the security group to VPC and not create it...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A security group can be **CREATED** per VPC, and then you can **ASSOCIATE** it with other objects in your account, such as Instances, ELBs, etc.

You cannot create cross-VPC security groups if that is your intention.

If you have multiple VPCs with similar rules, you must create a relevant security group for each VPC separately.

Comment: That was my intention, Thanks